# Encoding Transaction Arguments

Tags: raw-transaction, ios

I am building a simple high level library for off chain Ethereum transactions following ethereumjs-tx.

From what I read and understand:

1) Transaction parameters such as "nonce","to","gas","gasPrice","value","data","v","s","v" are all RLP encoded, striping any leading zeros.

2) Contract function execution parameters are all padded (left or right).

My question, are my assertions (1,2) correct and why not also have stripped parameters for the function calls?